# Pop-up window in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a C# WPF application which show uses Grid control in the xaml(P screen).For every row in the grid, I've a column called Details.Clicking on item in this column shows a pop-up windows which also has a grid in the xaml(C screen).
My item click event in the P's  viewmodel has the following code:

```
var myChildWindow = new MyGridView();
myChildWindow.Show();
```

If the user clicks on the item multiple times, I just want to highlight the existing C pop-up window.If there's no existing windows open, then only I want to open a new windows.

I've worked on a similar requirement for Winforms applicaiton.How do I go about this for  a WPF application please?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a no code behind project?

Answer (score 1):

First you'd need to declare `myChildWindow` outside of the click event so that it is accessible from multiple events. So,

```
MyGridView myChildWindow;
```

goes outside the click event, probably as a private variable.

Then, in your click event see if it's `null`, and if it is, create it.

```
if (myChildWindow == null)
{
    myChildWindow = new MyGridView();
    myChildWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sach for the response. But using this approach, for e.g. if a row # 3's pop-up window is already active and if i click on say row # 5 pop-up, new window wont be opened and instead it would highlight/activate the existing window itself.
In my application, every row passes some data to the pop-up window...hence its different pop-up for each row.

Comment: Immediate solution; have a separate window representing each row. But I do sense a bigger problem with your design here. A pop-up or any kind of form/window is a device to display information. So having a different instance of a window for _each_ row is rather substantial redundancy. You might want to rethink your approach; have one window, and depending on what row the user clicks, display appropriate data to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a reference to the window and get rid of this when the window is closed:

```
MyGridView  myChildWindow;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myChildWindow == null)
    {
        myChildWindow = new MyGridView();
        myChildWindow.Closed += MyChildWindow_Closed;
        myChildWindow.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        myChildWindow.Activate();
    }
}

private void MyChildWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myChildWindow.Closed -= MyChildWindow_Closed;
    myChildWindow = null;
}
```